# Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, remote-server

I am using mysql database, I was deploying my database with some hosting company and it was working fine but they suck so I migrated to upCloud. now I am facing a problem connecting to the database and getting an error:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

```
    $servername = 'localhost';
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = 'dbname';

 try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=driver", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 but no luck, I also tried manipulating single quote and double quote in strings but also it didn't work. can you advise on why I am getting this error?
I am deploying this in Ubonto 16.04

Comment: What was upCloud's recommendation for connecting to the database?

Comment: what do you mean by 'recommendations'?

Comment: Did upCloud tell you how your database was configured? Does it have a private IP? Is it located on the same instance your web site is located?

Comment: the thing is, my app contains Rest apis using the database and its working fine. but this is when using php pdo to connect, I get this error.
actually I just installed mysql in my Ubunto server
yes its located in the same instance, because for the Rest apis(which is working ) username is : localhost

Comment: Look at your /etc/hosts on the remote server. If it's empty, you need to add '127.0.0.1 localhost' to it.

Unless it's one of the varieties of VPS where the loopback interface hits the outer machine; on those, you need to use your VPS's IP number instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: wisam@wisamapps:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain  localhost
127.0.1.1    wisamapps

this what is in the hosts file, I tried 127.0.1.1 but no luck!

Comment: You may have to contact upCloud for support.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your DB connection details (host, DB name, username and password).

If it still does not work, then apparently there is a bug recently discovered and reported on Ubuntu, ***which fixes itself if you restart your Server.***

More details are listed here:

1. **Bug reported at Ubuntu:**
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733
2. **Another StackOverflow link where this issue is reported and discussed:**
   [PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926075/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-faile)

Hope it helps :)

---

**EDIT:**

Ubuntu has apparently released a fix as well: https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3239-2/

Update your version of Ubuntu and libraries as listed at this page.